# python error handling filepath is incorrect when run as a module

Tags: python

So I have a 2 files.

test.py

```
import sys
import error_handler
sys.excepthook = error_handler;
value = 23/0; #this line will throw Zero division error
```

error_handler.py

```
def custom_error_handler(ex_class, ex, tb):
    fileName = os.path.split(tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1];
    lineNo = tb.tb_lineno;
    print fileName;
    print lineNo;
```

These are the outputs when I run the file and when I run it as a module.

> python test.py
>
> test.py
>
> 4

But if I run

> python -m test
>
> runpy.py
>
> 162

Any ideas on why running it the second way produces that result? is there another way I should be doing this?

Thankyou.

Comment: Print out the whole `tb` rather than just one frame - you should spot where the problem comes from.

Comment: Looks like if you run a module, you're really launching the script `runpy.py` which then imports the module... That seems normal.

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved this by following [viraptors](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31667/viraptor) comment and the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html).

I had to import traceback, split the traceback into an array

```
import traceback;
tb_array = traceback.extract_tb(tb);
```

each element in the array is an array that contains:

- file path
- line number
- method name
- line string